# Definite integral using properties

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals, inverse-function

Find the value of the following integral.$$\int_{0}^{4\pi} \ln|13\sin x+3\sqrt3 
\cos x|\;\rm dx$$

**My attempt**: Using the properties of definite integral, I converted it to this integral.
$$4\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln|14\sin(x+\arctan(\frac{3\sqrt3}{13}))|\;\rm dx$$Please tell me how to proceed further.

Comment: It doesn't have a nice answer...

Comment: *Hint.* Since $x\mapsto\left|\sin x\right|$ is $\pi$-periodic, one can conclude that the integral in question is equal to $$4\int_{0}^{\pi}\log\left|14\sin x\right|\,\mathrm{d}x=4\pi\log14+8\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\left|\sin x\right|\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ Can you proceed from here?

Comment: How u got that integral?

Comment: Here is a general observation: Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be $T$-periodic and integrable on any finite interval. Then $$\int_{0}^{T}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{T}f(x+a)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$. It should be intuitively true by meditating on the graph of $f$, and the actual proof is also a fun exercise.

Comment: Isnt this property valid for any integral?. If at all there was an coefficient before \x in \f(x+a), we divide the whole integral by that coefficient.

Comment: Certainly you are not claiming that $$\frac{1}{2}=\int_{0}^{1}x\,\mathrm{d}x\stackrel{?}=\int_{0}^{1}(x+a)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}+a.$$ It is true that we have $$\int_{0}^{T}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\color{red}{-a}}^{\color{red}{T-a}}f(x+a)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ for any integrable function $f$ on $[0,T]$ via the substitution $x\mapsto x+a$. However, when $f$ is $T$-periodic, the shifted domain of integration in the right-hand side can be brought back to the original one, or even more generally, to any interval of length $T$.

Comment: Please put it as an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: @SangchulLee I have added a specific question using your name. Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

$$I=4\pi \ln 14+\int_{0}^{4\pi} \ln \sin (x+\alpha)~ dx$$
Let $x+\alpha=t$, then
$$I=4\pi\ln 14+ \int_{\alpha}^{4\pi+\alpha} \log \sin t dt$$
Since integrand is periodic funxtion eyj period $2\pi$ then
$$I=4\pi \ln 14+2\int_{0}^{2\pi} \ln \sin t ~ dt~~~~(1)$$
Use $$\int_{0}^{2a} f(x) dx= \int_{0}^{a} [f(x)+f(2a-x)] dx ~~~~~~~(2)$$
Using (1), we get
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \ln \sin t dt=\int_{0}^{\pi} [\ln \sin t+ \ln (-\sin t)]_~dt= i\pi^2+2\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln \sin t~ dt$$
Using (1) again, we get
$$K=\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln \sin t~ dt= 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin t ~dt= 2 J$$
$$\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx=\int_{0}^{a} f(a-x) dx~~~~~(3)$$

$$J=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln \sin t dt \implies \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln \cos t ~dt \implies 2J=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln (\frac{\sin 2t}{2}) dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln \sin u~du-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2$$ $$2J=K/2-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2 \implies J=-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2$$

Finally, using there results in (1), we get
$$I=4\pi\ln 14+2i\pi^2-4\pi \ln 2=4\pi \ln 7+2i\pi^2$$

Comment: Please why do you use $i$ for $\int_0^{2\pi} \ln \sin t \mathrm d t$?

Comment: Because $\ln(-\sin{t}) = \ln(-1)+\ln(\sin{t}) = i\pi+\ln(\sin{t})$ @Sebastiano

Comment: @Notsredt I have understood, for my students I have not used immaginary logaritm, if I not remember well, is $i\pi$ with the argument $\arg$.

Comment: The original integral is the integral of a real function, so the outcome cannot be complex. In $(1)$ you should have considered $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log\color{red}{\left|\sin t\right|}\,dt$$