# Periodic functions for the definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals, proof-writing, periodic-functions, upper-lower-bounds

Considering this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765093/definite-integral-using-properties) where there is this integral:

$$\int_{0}^{4\pi} \ln|13\sin x+3\sqrt3 
\cos x|\mathrm dx \tag 1$$

Easily all the periodic function $$a'\sin(x)+b\cos(x)+c=0 \tag 2$$ can be written as:

$$A\sin(x+\phi)+c=0, \ A=\sqrt{a'^2+b^2}\quad \text{ or }\quad  A\cos(x+\varphi)+c=0\tag 3$$
where $\phi, \varphi=\arctan \ldots$ are angles definited in radians, hence $\in\Bbb R$.
Reading the comments of the user @Sangchul Lee, I think that $|\sin(x)|$ is a even-function and $\pi-$periodic,

$$\int_{0}^{4\pi} \ln|13\sin x+3\sqrt3 
\cos x|\,\mathrm{d}x=4\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln| A\sin(x+\phi)|\,\mathrm{d}x=4\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln(A| \sin(x+\phi)|)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

1. Why $\phi$ vanished? It is true if $\phi=K\pi$, with $K\in\Bbb Z$. I not remember this now.
2. Considering the comment "Let $f:\mathbb R→\mathbb R$ be $T$-periodic and integrable on any finite interval then
   $∫_0^Tf(x)dx=∫_0^Tf(x+a)dx$" when is it useful, for a periodic function,

$$\int_{0}^{T}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{T}f(x+a)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\color{red}{-a}}^{\color{red}{T-a}}f(x+a)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

and if are there general rules (or what is it happen) for the limits of the integral of a generic periodic function?

$$\int_{\color{blue}{\lambda}}^{\color{blue}{\mu}}f(x+a)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\color{blue}{\lambda}}^{\color{blue}{\mu}}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=C\int_{\color{magenta}{\cdots}}^{\color{magenta}{\cdots}}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
where $C=C(\lambda)$ (upper bound) or $C=C(\mu)$ (lower bound) is a real constant.

Comment: @Notsredt even function ("funzione pari"); sometimes I done a mistake odd/even in English language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $13^2+27=14^2$, so
$$ 13\sin(x)+3\sqrt{3}\cos(x) = 14\sin(x+\varphi),\qquad \varphi=\arctan\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{13}\not\in\pi\mathbb{Z} $$
and
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{4\pi}\log\left|13\sin(x)+3\sqrt{3}\cos(x)\right|\,dx &=& 4\pi\log(14)+\int_{0}^{4\pi}\log\left|\sin x\right|\,dx\\&=&4\pi\log(14)+4\int_{0}^{\pi}\log\sin(x)\,dx\end{eqnarray*}$$
where
$$\begin{eqnarray*} I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\log\sin(x)\,dx &=& 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\sin(2z)\,dz\\&=&\pi\log(2)+2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\sin(z)\,dz+2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\cos(z)\,dz\\&=&\pi\log(2)+2I\end{eqnarray*}$$
leads to
$$\int_{0}^{4\pi}\log\left|13\sin(x)+3\sqrt{3}\cos(x)\right|\,dx =4\pi\log(14)-4\pi\log(2) = \color{red}{4\pi\log(7)}.$$

Comment: Always thank you and I ask always excuse me for my low level in English language. I have always a doubt.ì if exist a particular value of upper bound (low) where I have it is not possible to write $B\sin(x+\varphi)=B\sin x$, when $\varphi\notin k\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Sebastiano: the point is that we don't need $\varphi\in \pi\mathbb{Z}$: since $\sin$ is $2\pi$-periodic, $$ \int_{0}^{4\pi} g(\sin(x+\varphi))\,dx = \int_{0}^{4\pi}g(\sin x)\,dx $$ for *any* $\varphi$.

Comment: Yes, of course. :-)....$4\pi=2(2\pi)$. But for my 2nd request? :-) "Grazie assai".

Comment: @Sebastiano: if the length of the integration range is not a multiple of the period the identity $$ \int_{\mu}^{\lambda}f(x+a)\,dx = \int_{\mu}^{\lambda}f(x)\,dx $$ is not granted to hold. *Prego* ;)

Comment: When you have a bit of your precious time can you put some example for the last comment, please. Best regards from Sicily.

Comment: Easily done: consider $f(x)=\sin(x)$, $\mu=\pi/4, \lambda=\pi/3$ and $a=\pi/2$.